# Commit changes after process modified files

Tags: python, git, gitpython

With `GitPython` I try to commit files that another process modified/deleted or added. But the [`commit`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#git.index.base.IndexFile.commit) function does not work as I expected.

```
branch = r.create_head('feature1')
subprocess.Popen(args=modify files)

index = r.index # get current head!?
diff = index.diff(None)  # diff against the working copy
index.commit(message="New Feature")
```

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I even receive a `git.Commit` object, but when I open the directory in a tool like `Visual Studio Code` I still see the unstaged changes in my new created feature branch which were supposed to be committed.

Comment: Looks like your question is incomplete.

Comment: I think what you might be missing is `index.add([<list_of_files_to_add_to_index>])`

Comment: I thought that's what a `index.diff` could do for me